# Calling WCF hosted on a different server from Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, wcf, json

In all the walkthroughs of calling WCF from Javascript, the svc file is part of the WebApplication that calls WCF.
However, what happens if the service endpoint is hosted on a different server? Would I start running into Cross-Domain issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not going to be able to achieve truly "regular WCF behavior." However, its quite possible to call JSONP from WCF as all the tutorials will tell you.

Now if you just want to be able to declare the endpoint of your service in your web.config you can simple stick this in your aspx file.

var url = '<%= ConfigurationManager.ApplicationSettings['endpoint']  %>';

Then just add an endpoint to the appSettings sections of the web.config.

Comment: Thanks Justin. However, what if the service is hosted in a different domain/different machine than the client. Will the browser allow that call?

Comment: If you make a JSONP endpoint and not a json endpoint then yes. WCF is capable of JSONP as well as JSON endpoints.